# React Native AsyncStorage not returning values before the next function is executed when using async / await

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, native, asyncstorage

I am working on a react native project where a user is presented with a splash screen and the splash screen reads in from AsyncStorage to check if this is the first the user is using the app if so they are directed to a tour screen after which they go to the home screen once they press continue button. When the user presses continue a key is set and a value using AsyncStorage (key firstUse with a value of false).

Now when I go back into the app the tour page is loaded again. When I look at the console log, I've noticed that checkFirstUse function is returning the value as undefined before the getSettings function is completed executing (these values are outputted after). I assumed that getSettings runs first until a response is returned (as the function uses async / await) but clearly not working any help in resolveing this is appreciated.

Here is the code (stripped down for simplicity)

SplashScreen:

```
@inject("settingsStore")
class SplashScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.settingsStore.getSettings();
    this.checkFirstUse();
  }

  checkFirstUse = () => {
    console.log(' is this first use '+this.props.settingsStore.settings.firstUse);
    if (this.props.settingsStore.settings.firstUse === 'false') {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
    }else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('TourScreen')
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the SPLASH SCREEN</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default SplashScreen;
```

SettingsStore:

```
export default class SettingsStore {
  @observable settings = [];

  @action async getSettings() {
    try{
      var response = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['firstUse', 'userID']);
      this.settings.firstUse = response[0][1];
      this.settings.UserID = response[1][1];
      console.log('got settings'); 
      console.log(response);    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  @action async setFirstUse() {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('firstUse', 'false');
      this.settings.firstUse = 'false';
      console.log('Have set first use');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So i have updated my code in SplashScreen:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await this.props.settingsStore.getSettings();
  await this.checkFirstUse();
}
```

This seems to be working I will test further and report back.